# Unity Platformer Script Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I apologize if this is a very basic question; I am new to unity and just learning. I am trying to make a small game on unity, but am having problems with a code involving a moving platform. When the player is on the platform, and the platform is moving, I want the player to move with it. However, I can't seem to get it to work. The code for my player movement is as below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float walkSpeed = 4.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpHeight = 2.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float gravity = -9.81f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float rotationSpeed = 5.0f;

    private CharacterController characterController;
    private PlayerInput playerInput;
    private Transform cameraTransform;

    private InputAction moveAction;
    private InputAction jumpAction;

    private Vector3 playerVelocity;
    private bool isGrounded;

    private void Awake()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        playerInput = GetComponent<PlayerInput>();

        cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;

        moveAction = playerInput.actions["Walk"];
        jumpAction = playerInput.actions["Jump"];

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = characterController.isGrounded;

        if (isGrounded && playerVelocity.y < 0)
        {
            playerVelocity.y = -5.0f;
            gravity = -9.81f;
        }

        Vector2 input = moveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();

        Vector3 move = new Vector3(input.x, 0f, input.y);

        Vector3 cameraForwardDirection = new Vector3(Camera.main.transform.forward.x, 0, Camera.main.transform.forward.z);
        Vector3 cameraRightDirection = new Vector3(Camera.main.transform.right.x, 0, Camera.main.transform.right.z);

        move = cameraForwardDirection * move.z + cameraRightDirection * move.x;

        characterController.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * walkSpeed);

        if (jumpAction.triggered && isGrounded)
        {
            playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravity);
        }

        playerVelocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        characterController.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);

        float targetAngle = cameraTransform.eulerAngles.y;
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, targetAngle, 0);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void PlatformMovement(Vector3 platformVelocity)
    {
        characterController.Move(platformVelocity);
    }
}
```

The code I am using to move my player with the platform is below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformStick : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            PlayerMovement playerMovement = other.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();

            Rigidbody rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

            playerMovement.PlatformMovement(rigidbody.velocity);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using a Debug.Log() to see if the PlatformMovement() method was being called, and it seems to be, its just that the movement is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you could make the player as children of the platform when the player touch the platform.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformStick : MonoBehaviour
{

\\When the player land on the platform.
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
           other.gameObject.transform.setParent(this.transform);
        }
    }

\\For when the player jumps or leave the platform.
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
           other.gameObject.transform.setParent(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried doing that at first, but it seems that even when the player is parented to the platform, it doesn't move with it. I can see that it's parented in the hierarchy but it doesn't move, which is why I'm trying this out.